# Tsql returning error on sub query when using Min and Max

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm running 2 tables the first (tiereport) hold email address, working day start and end time.
The second hold email address and login and logout time for each day of which there may be several login and logouts against each person.

Using the following query to obtain any person who has logged in late or left early

```
SELECT Email,
       StartTime,
       EndTime
FROM tierreport
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(TimeIn) AS TimeIn,
                       MAX(TimeOut) AS TimeOut
                FROM InOutUserCurrentStatus) IO ON (IO.Email = Email)
WHERE tierreport.Email = 'fred.bloks@xyz.com'
  AND IO.Date >= '2019-11-01'
  AND IO.Date <= '2019-11-29'
  AND (IO.TimeIn > StartTime
    OR IO.TimeOut < EndTime);
```

However continuously get an error at stating 'error 207 invalided column name Email, Invalided column name Date' am I missing something

Comment: `(SELECT MIN(TimeIn) AS TimeIn, MAX(TimeOut) AS TimeOut FROM) ... AS IO` ... there is indeed no columns `IO.Email` nor `IO.Date`

Comment: IO is the alas for the InOutUserCurrentStautus  "FROM InOutUserCurrentStatus) IO"

Comment: no, in the SQL it's an alias for the nested SELECT, you may check it by doing `SELECT IO.* FROM ...`

Comment: Aside: Best practice is to use table aliases on all column references when using joins. That avoids confusion from code like `IO.Email = Email`. Does that just filter out NULLs or is it really comparing two different columns?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation in the subquery:

```
SELECT tr.Email, tr.StartTime, tr.EndTime
FROM tierreport tr LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT IO.Email,
             MIN(TimeIn) AS TimeIn, MAX(TimeOut) AS TimeOut
      FROM InOutUserCurrentStatus
      GROUP BY IO.Email
     ) IO
     ON IO.Email = tr.Email
WHERE tr.Email = 'fred.bloks@xyz.com' AND
      IO.Date >= '2019-11-01' AND
      IO.Date <= '2019-11-29' AND
      (IO.TimeIn > StartTime OR IO.TimeOut < EndTime);
```

Note:  You are using a `LEFT JOIN`, but the `WHERE` clause converts this to an `INNER JOIN`.

Alternatively, you can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT Email, StartTime, EndTime
FROM tierreport tr OUTER APPLY JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(TimeIn) AS TimeIn, MAX(TimeOut) AS TimeOut
      FROM InOutUserCurrentStatus
      WHERE IO.Email = tr.Email AND
            IO.Date >= '2019-11-01' AND
            IO.Date <= '2019-11-29' AND
            (IO.TimeIn > tr.StartTime OR IO.TimeOut < tr.EndTime)
     ) IO         
WHERE tr.Email = 'fred.bloks@xyz.com';
```

This behaves as you presumably intend, because it acts more like an outer join.